# Space Complexity for this method

Tags: java, algorithm

Would the worst case space complexity for this method be O(1) or O(n)?

```
 public Node<E> search(E item) {
    Node<E> node = null;
    if (head!=null) {
        node = head;
        while (node!=null && !node.item.equals(item)) {
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: O(1), you only create one node which is not dependent on the size of the list. If your search function uses O(n) space there is an issue

Comment: remember that space complexity is the extra space created to solve a particular problem, it does not take space required by input into account.

Comment: What do you think? Share your thoughts / findings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question shows no effort to find an answer himself.

Answer (score 0):

```
O(1)
```

There is no space allocation in the listed method. The code is traversing over the nodes that have been *previously* allocated.